# SQL Filter days equal to or higher than the 25th of the month

Tags: sql, hana

I have two columns: reporting_month and scheduled_sales_date. On the scheduled_sales_date, I want to filter and show only dates with days equal to or higher than 25 of the month.

Default table :

```
reporting_month scheduled_sales_date
202212          20230117
202212          20230106
202212          20230125
202212          20230130
202212          20230101
202212          20230129
202212          20230114
202212          20230122
202212          20230129
```

Expected filtered table:

```
reporting_month scheduled_sales_date
202212          20230125
202212          20230130
202212          20230129
202212          20230129
```

Comment: ...WHERE TO_INTEGER(DAYOFMONTH(scheduled_sales_date)) >= 25? I have no environment to test it, but this should do.

Comment: What is the type of the scheduled_sales_date column ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what data type scheduled_sales_date is. You should store dates as dates, of course, not as numbers or strings. But we can't be sure.

### for a date '2023-01-17' use:

```
where extract(day from scheduled_sales_date) >= 25
```

https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/20e1a58475191014a343f6fe96c9846c.html

### For a numeric 20230117 use:

```
where mod(scheduled_sales_date, 10) >= 25
```

https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/20e51e5c751910149879aa97a95d564b.html

### for a string '20230117' use:

```
where substring(scheduled_sales_date, 7, 2) >= '25'
```

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20e8341275191014a4cfdcd3c830fc98.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned whether the scheduled_sales_date is a number field or a date field if it is a date field then
`TO_INTEGER(DAYOFMONTH(scheduled_sales_date)) >= 25` should work
else if it is a number field then you can use
`scheduled_sales_date >=(year*10000+month*100+25)`

Comment: Do you really need `TO_INTEGER`? Doesn't `DAYOFMONTH` already return a number?

Comment: @Rafalon According to this [documentation](https://sapcodes.com/2020/06/21/hana-sql-date-and-time-functions/) it returns NVARCHAR(2). That's why I also guessed it's needed to cast to int in my comment above. My question here would be if it matters whether the column is an int or a date column. Isn't DAYOFMONTH able to process it anyway? Even if not, they should rather alter the table and make the column a date column than change the query as proposed in this answer.

Comment: [This SAP HANA SQL Reference Guide](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20e133a875191014a958bb2c7dd5d960.html) states that `DAYOFMONTH` "*Returns an integer for the day of the month for the specified date*". Unfortunately, I have no way to actually test it

Comment: Well, at least, this should be sufficient help and OP can test if cast to int is necessary or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT reporting_month, scheduled_sales_date
FROM your_table_name
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(scheduled_sales_date) >= 25;
```

```
reporting_month | scheduled_sales_date
-------------------------------------
202212          | 20230125
202212          | 20230130
202212          | 20230129
202212          | 20230129
```

[DAYOFMONTH (d)](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20e133a875191014a958bb2c7dd5d960.html?q=DAYOFMONTH)

Comment: I couldn't find `DAY(datetime)` in SAP HANA SQL documentation, did you try your code?

Comment: @Rafalon yes you are right I didn't pay attention that you are using SAP Hana I updated the query

Comment: Then you can just delete the answer because it's a copy of the other.

Comment: My concern is about the type of the scheduled_sales_date because it doesn't seem to be in a date format seems like internal format